# Selecting multiple files in FileDialog to send to an email

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add multiple files when opening My Documents. I currently have a command button and when clicked the file dialog window is opened.

I am able to select as many as I can, however when it is emailed to the address it only shows 2 attachments, the first one being the form on the spreadsheet and the second being the file chosen from the file dialog window.

How can I add more than 2 attachments to my email?

I've tried using a For Loop, so there can be many attachments, however this is not working.

Please see below.

```
Sub SbExtra_Attachment()
  'mssgbox do you have another attachment to add ?
   Response = MsgBox(prompt:="Do you have any other attachments? 'Yes'or 'No'.", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

If Response = vbYes Then

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

        If fd.Show = -1 Then
            For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            StrFile = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            Next i

        End If

    Else

End If

End Sub
```

The above currently only attaches a maximum of 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this to your needs:

```
Sub Test()

    'You already have similar lines somewhere, so adapt the code later on
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim ToRecipient As String
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(OlMailItem)
    OlMail.Recipients.Add "test@test.com"
    OlMail.Subject = "Test message"
    'end of code you will already have

    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim attachments() As String

    strFile = SbExtra_Attachment(strFile, "Do you have any attachments? 'Yes'or 'No'.")

    If strFile <> "" Then

        attachments = Split(strFile, ";")

        For cnt = 0 To UBound(attachments)

            'Replace "OlMail" with the name of the Mail Object variable that you created
            With OlMail

                .attachments.Add attachments(cnt)

            End With

        Next cnt

    End If

    'Send the e-mail here
    OlMail.Send

    Set OlMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function SbExtra_Attachment(fileCollection As String, FilePrompt As String) As String

    Dim Response As Integer
    Dim lngCount As Integer

    'mssgbox do you have another attachment to add ?
    Response = MsgBox(Prompt:=FilePrompt, Buttons:=vbYesNo)

    If Response = vbYes Then

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

            .AllowMultiSelect = True
            .Show

            For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.count

                If Len(fileCollection) > 0 Then fileCollection = fileCollection & ";"
                fileCollection = fileCollection & .SelectedItems(lngCount)

            Next lngCount

        End With
        fileCollection = SbExtra_Attachment(fileCollection, "Do you have any other attachments? 'Yes'or 'No'.")
    End If

    SbExtra_Attachment = fileCollection

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Davy

I currently have a separate code to send the email on a different module.

```
If strFile = "" Then
   Else
     .Attachments.Add (strFile)
End If
```

strFile is publicly declared, how can I combine the code so it is able to capture the files.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to change this code to a Function, passing in the existing "strFile", and returning it with the extra values added. I have updated the code above along with an example showing how to call it. I am assuming you have "strFile" declared as a Variant?

Comment: I've declared it as a String, should I change this to a Variant?

Comment: How are you planning on using the variable? If you want to store a collection of items then it would make sense to store them in a type that can handle a collection eg. a variant array. If you follow my code above, then you can just set strFile(1) = <the first attachment file name>

Comment: Ok thanks, but that would that mean the user will need to follow the same path to attach a file, how can I make them choose any file

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here? I thought that the initial attachment was coming from a Cell value in Excel? Surely, you just make strFile(1) = <cell value> and then call the SbExtraAttachments() Function? Can you try explaining what you are trying to do a little clearer? Thanks, D.

Comment: Sorry Dave. I'm trying to attach files from the file directory on my computer not an excel spreadsheet, so a user it able to select as many files as they can (all would be different), which is then sent to an email address on Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code Davy. But I keep getting an error here:

 .Attachments.Add (strFile) 

just before the dot at attachments, it says invalid or unqualified reference. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you post up the rest of your code, you should have the .Attachments.Add in a WITH statement. I posted this as an example based on the lines you gave me, but I can see the format is wrong (strFile needs to be split out and the files added).

Comment: Code updated. I am "guessing" at what the parts of your missing code look like, but this is a full and complete "send mail with multiple attachments" code.